# Setting choices without playing the previous games

Tags: pc, the-witcher-3, the-witcher-2, the-witcher, the-witcher-series

I've played the first The Witcher some time ago now and I remember it already felt dated when I played it.
I never finished it but I did make almost to the end and I eventualoly watched a long play to know how the story ended.

I'm interested in experiencing the whole trilogy and carrying the choices from game to game but since the first game will feel extremely dated to me and will probably be just an annoying grind at this point (since I've played most of it once) I'm wondering if there's a way to simply set the key choices from the first game to the second.

Is there an official way to set these choices or will I have to somehow create a save file to import to The Witcher 2?
How about setting choices from the first 2 games in The Witcher 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some differences between Witcher 2 and 3 in this regard, so I cover them separatly.

### Witcher 2

You can find some savegames [here](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1900752). Just choose the one you want and import it. I dont know about another way to carry over the choices to Witcher 2.

### Witcher 3

You can find some savegames from Witcher 2 [here](http://www.nexusmods.com/witcher2/mods/searchresults/?src_cat=34). However, you get the opportunity to simulate some choices from Witcher 2 in the Prolog of Witcher 3.
Also you might as well consider just playing Witcher 2 yourself. It doesn't take that much time to play throught. Fun fact: [You can actually finish the game in ~4 hours](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8laixF6N7aU). If you play normally you need around 40 hours.

Some more googling might find you some savegames, I just linked the first I found here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am planning on playing The Witcher 2 but for the sake of completeness I figured I might as well ask for the third game as well :).